# Graphene-Django not Sending HTTPOnly JWT Cookie to React-Apollo

Tags: cookies, graphql, jwt, apollo, httponly

Hi so I've been making an app using `Django` and `Graphene` for a `GraphQL` server that will be accessed by a `React` client using `Apollo`. I'm using `graphql_jwt` for authentication.

I have set up my GraphQL server and the client code to read the JWT but I've learned that localStorage is not safe enough and neither is a cookie. I managed to find a way to set an HTTPOnly cookie when making the tokenAuth request and the cookie persists and is functional in GraphiQL (localhost:8000).

[image: JWT HHTPOnly Cookies Set]

I managed to do this with `jwt_cookie` decorator from `graphql_jwt.decorators`

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from graphene_django.views import GraphQLView
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from graphql_jwt.decorators import jwt_cookie

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('graphql/', jwt_cookie(csrf_exempt(GraphQLView.as_view(graphiql=True))))
]
```

Unfortunately, when I call the tokenAuth endpoint from Apollo (localhost:3000) it is neither setting the cookie nor is can I access it from my afterware (makes sense now that I think about it). Neither the `same-origin` or `include` credentials work in the server `HttpLink` or the `ApolloClient` itself.

```
import { 
  ApolloClient, 
  gql, 
  ApolloProvider, 
  HttpLink, 
  from,
  useQuery,
  ApolloLink
} from '@apollo/client';
import { onError } from '@apollo/client/link/error';
import { setContext } from 'apollo-link-context';

const errorLink = onError(({ graphQLErrors, networkError }) => {
  if (graphQLErrors) {
    graphQLErrors.forEach(({ message }) => {
      console.log(message);
    });
  }
  if (networkError) {
    console.log(networkError.message)
  }
});
const afterwareLink = new ApolloLink((operation, forward) => {
  return forward(operation).map(response => {
    const context = operation.getContext();
    const { response: { headers } } = context;
    console.log(headers);
    return response;
  });
});


const link = from([
  errorLink,
  setContext((operation) => {
    console.log("HITTING SET CONTEXT");
    // const token = localStorage.getItem('authToken');
    const token = Cookies.get('authToken');
    console.log(token);
    return {
      headers: {
        Authorization: token ? `JWT ${token}` : ''
      }
    }
  }),
  afterwareLink,
  new HttpLink({ uri: 'http://localhost:8000/graphql/' })
]);

const client = new ApolloClient({
  link,
  cache,
  typeDefs,
  credentials: 'include'
});
```

Please ignore the `refreshToken` and `authToken` values. I set them with the `js-cookie` package. But as you can see the Headers are empty and weren't set on login on the client but they were on the server.

[image]

QUESTION:

How do I pass the jwt response headers to the frontend?

Answer (score 0):

SO I was able to resolve this. I posted my resolution on Github

https://github.com/flavors/django-graphql-jwt/issues/191